# How to restrict the entry of duplicate emails (ie that are already present in my database)?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

This code is for inserting a new record:

```
var user=require('mongoose').model("UserProfile");
user.createAccountPage=function(req,res)
{
    var UserSchema=new user(req.body);
    UserSchema.save(function(err,obj){
        if(!err)
        {
            console.log("Created Account")
            var outPut={
                msg:"Created Account",
                data:obj

            }
            res.json(outPut)
        }
        else
        {
             console.log(err);
            console.log("Not created Account")
            var outPut={
                msg:"Not created Account",
                data:err


            }
            res.json(outPut)
        }



    })
```

This is the script to save the data on db:

```
 $("#submitButton").click(function()
            {
                var Name=$("#inputName").val();
                var Father_Name=$("#inputFatherName").val();
                var Email=$("#inputEmail").val();
                var Phone=$("#inputNumber").val();
                var CreateAccountDataObj={
                    Name:Name,
                    Father_Name:Father_Name,
                    Email:Email,
                    Phone:Phone
                }
```

And this is the ajax code

```
 $.ajax({
                url: '/createAccount',
                // dataType: "jsonp",
                data: CreateAccountDataObj,
                type: 'POST',
                jsonpCallback: 'callback', // this is not relevant to the POST anymore
                success: function(data) {
                    //var ret = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

                    console.log(data)
                    $("#Name").text(data.data.Name);
                    $("#Father").text(data.data.Father);
                    $("#Email").text(data.data.Email);
                    $("#Number").text(data.data.Number);
                    $(".hideAndShow").show();
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    console.log('Error: ' + error.message);

                },
            });
```

I need to restrict the entry of duplicate emails using NodeJS. I am trying this. I am using MongoDB as database and ExpressJS too.

Comment: did you try marking email field as unique (https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/unique-constraints-on-arbitrary-fields/)?

Comment: yes i tried but nothing worked

Comment: tq fragmentedreality it workss now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add this to your schema `{unique: true}`:

```
new Schema({
  email: { 
    type: String,
    unique: true
  }
})
```

Comment: np, glad to help